# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration system failed to initialize'

Tags: .net, winforms, ms-access, exception, connection-string

All works fine but suddenly i get this error. Connection string automatically generated by program.

[image]

This is my App.config file i didn't change anything. DB file is on the same place like it was. Any suggestion?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FBAutoPost.Properties.Settings.FBGroupAutoPostDBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Resources\FacebookGroupAutoPostDB.accdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
   <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception popup shows the "Inner Exception":

> ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section userSettings.

It's reading a config file with a "userSettings" configuration section in it. It looks like it's not reading the config file that you think it is.

Comment: I don't have userSettings section anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, so it's not reading the file you think it is. Use something like SysInternals File Monitor to find out which file it _is_ reading.

Comment: ...or just deliberately screw up your `App.config` file (with unmatched XML or something) and see if it complains about that instead.

Comment: I deleted some part of code from `App.config` (connectionSetring and startup) and the same error showed. So app don't read App.config. With SysInternals File Monitor i didn't find anything. This exception does not allow to program start.

Comment: Check this picture: https://s12.postimg.org/hwyuqllgd/Capture.png What this can be?

Comment: "I deleted some part of code". You misunderstand me. You need to *f£$% up* the config file so that it's no longer valid XML. You're trying to find out whether your app continues to barf on the userSettings thing, or on your newly screwed up config file. Removing XML nodes cleanly doesn't do that.

Comment: Your picture shows VS looking to see if you're working in a git working directory. Nothing unusual here. (Unless you're not using any kind of source control, which would be unusual).

Comment: Well, something isn't correct with binding. I am binding one table to DataGridView.